# Tags pages for different Custom Post Types and WooCommerce Products sharing Post Tags

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pagination, rewrite-rules

I have these post types :
- Articles (blog),
- Hotels (custom post type),
- Products Activities (WooCommerce products with a product_cat Activities)
- Products Transportation (WooCommerce products with product_cat Transportation).

**All these post types can be linked to a single tag (the default Wordpress Post Tags).**

I want distinct tags URLs for each post type, like this :
- Articles : `/tag/{tag}` (the default one, working normally, with pagination etc.)
- Hotels : `/hotels/tag/{tag}`
- Activities : `/activities/tag/{tag}`
- Transportation : `/transportation/tag/{tag}`

For the last 3 I managed to setup custom rewrite rules to have these URI working :

- Hotels :
  `add_rewrite_rule( 'hotels/([^/]+)', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&post_type=hotels', 'top' );`
  and for pagination :
  `add_rewrite_rule( 'hotels/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&post_type=hotels&pages=$matches[2]', 'top' );`
- Products Activities :
  `add_rewrite_rule( 'activities/tag/([^/]+)', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&product_cat=activities', 'top' );`
  and for pagination :
  `add_rewrite_rule( 'activities/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&product_cat=activities&pages=$matches[2]', 'top' );`
- Products Transportation :
  `add_rewrite_rule( 'transportation/tag/([^/]+)', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&product_cat=transportation', 'top' );`
  and for pagination :
  `add_rewrite_rule( 'transportation/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&product_cat=transportation&pages=$matches[2]', 'top' );`

This is working for the Hotels query. For the products query it's working except for pagination. The pagination is well displayed on page 1, but if I click on page 2 button I go to `activites/tag/{tag}/page/2` but it stills displays page 1. Is there something special to do for WooCommerce ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out !
I just had to declare the paged rewrite rule before the non-paged rewrite rule...

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'activities/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&product_cat=activities&pages=$matches[2]', 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( 'activities/tag/([^/]+)', 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&product_cat=activities', 'top' );
```